# How can I set the jdk in an eclipse portable version?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I installed Eclipse portable and installed it on a drive. Everything worked fine. On the same disk is a Java Version.

If I start Eclipse and want to create a Java Project how I did it in the past, it will not work. There is no jdk set. I looked up the problem on the internet and just found a fix where you have to set the jdk file in the setings under the bulletpoint Java but it's not there.

Does anybody know a fix? Any suggestions? - Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to install the jdk on the same portable drive and use a relative path in eclipse.ini.

Answer (score 1):

In the portable version of Eclipse, inside eclipse folder open the file **eclipse.ini** in notepad or notepad++ and add the following in the last. Before this, you have to close the eclipse.

> -vm C:\Java\JDK\1.8.0\bin\javaw.exe

After making changes, you can start eclipse. For more details, refer this link.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: Are spaces allowed in the folder name?

Comment: Give complete path of Jdk like C:\dev\jdk1.8.0\bin like this.

Comment: I still get no Java Project. Simply does not load.

Comment: `-vm` and the path **must** be on separate lines in the eclipse.ini. These lines **must** be before any `-vmargs` line.

Comment: [It’s good that this software has a documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM)